# Asus UX31 power button's action menu

Tags: windows-7, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

I have problem with my asus ux31. I came with win7 and lots of unnecessary stuff installed, so I installed win7 x64 from scratch. Hence there was one cool think, which I cannot find on Asus' webpage.

When you hit the power button a custom menu popped up with action to perform: hibernate, sleep, shut down etc. I want this option back, because power button is **very** close to backspace and I already missed several times :) Hence, I don't want to disable the power button at all. I want to keep the functionality and have some kind of a "confirmation" step :)

Anybody knows what should I install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Download page at Asus](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Superior_Mobility/ASUS_ZENBOOK_UX31E/#download), under Utilities, there is a PowerWiz installation that appears to have this within the sys file...

```
[UX31E]
full=0
Normal_s3 = 400
Deep_s3 = 200
Idle = 5767
Net = 7991
Movie= 9974
Music= 6679
Game =  12300
Office= 11308
```

Now.... if those options coincide with the shutdown options that you are talking about, this would be the file to download and install.

I'd also download Power Option as well, just to be sure.

Comment: Thans dude. Actually PowerWiz is that crappy, useless widget which shows how much time has left to sleep/shutdown. Power options is the correct one.

Comment: @SOReader you are welcome.  I thought it had to be one of the two... which is why I asked.  I didn't know Asus included a crappy widget that counted down shutdown time.